# Move HTML5 FullScreen (MAP) to a second screen

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, leaflet, html5-fullscreen

I am using a leaflet map in my AngularJS Application and searching for a solution for my issue iv'e got stucked in.

I want to move the Fullscreen of the Map to a second Screen (if available) so the user is able to continue using the application on the main-screen, but i cant find any solution and have no idea anymore...

Is there a way to get this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to get this done?

No.

The [WhatWG FullScreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) does **not** expose nor consider this functionality. See also [How to display content of DIV Tag of a HTML page on second monitor screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218706/how-to-display-content-of-div-tag-of-a-html-page-on-second-monitor-screen) and [Multiple monitors on one PC for a KIOSK system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425882/multiple-monitors-on-one-pc-for-a-kiosk-system)